# Reusing Drive API token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java

the above URL has a video that allows me to access a drive account and upload a file. But the problem is, that I want to access that account everytime the user logins into my software. Now the problem is that I cannot reuse the access token the user provides me. This makes him go through the entire process each and every time my application wants access.

Kindly tell me the way I can store his data and reuse it. Can saving and reusing the GoogleCredential object be a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about refresh tokens (not access token) and how to do the oauth flow requesting offline access. Then what you save is the refresh token which is used to get a new access token once it expires.
The oauth docs from google explain this in more detail.

Comment: Ya, I figured it out the same day. However, thank you